# Cannot find cause for Crystal Reports error "One or more fields cannot be found in the result set."

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that uses a stored procedure to retrieve data, it has 15 parameters and in Crystal they have defaults set up.

```
Company(tinyint) default: 0
PRGroup(tinyint) default: 0
EndDateorMonth(char(1)) default: blank space
BegDate(smalldatetime) default: 1/1/1950 00:00:00
EndDate(smalldatetime) defualt: 12/31/2050 00:00:00
BegMonth(smalldatetime) default: 1/1/1950 00:00:00
EndMonth(smalldatetime) default: 12/1/2050 00:00:00
BegSortName(varchar(15)) default: blank sapace
EndSortName(varchar(15)) default: zzzzzzzzzzzz
EarnType(char(1)) default: blank space
EarnCode(varchar(250)) default: blank space
TrueEarnOnly(char(1)) default: N
BegEmployee(int) default: 0
EndEmployee(int) default: 99999
EmployeeList(varchar(250)) default: blank space
```

When I run the report through Crystal and provide anything but 0 for PRGroup I get the error:

> One or more fields cannot be found in the result set.

But if I leave the Group as the default 0 I get the expected results. The only data displaying on the report is the employee number, employee name and roughly 300 columns with each being the earn type + earn code + amount type (subject, eligible or amount).

I really don't want to have to remove the database connection and start from scratch as I had to drag and drop all 300 fields onto the report. What could be the cause of the problem and potential solutions?

Comment: What is the range of values from the PRGroup? If you run the stored procedure with some thing other than 0 dose it produce results?

Comment: The values of PRGroup are: 0,1,2,3. You can enter anything within the constraints of tinyint but if you enter something other than 1-3 you won't get any results unless you enter 0 in which case you'll get all possible values for PRGroup (currently 1 - 3). 

If I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server I get the expected results whether I  enter 0, 1, 2 or 3 for PRGroup.

Answer (score 0):

What the stored procedure looks like , especially the code for the cases when group<>0 ?
If you are doing inserts or updates in this part then you need to add 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
at the beginning of the stored procedure

Comment: When the group parameter comes into the stored procedure I set it to Null if it's 0 and in my query I have: 
    (@PRGroup IS NULL OR (PRDT.PRGroup = @PRGroup))